# Get compilation errors in gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I wanted to ask how to get Compilation errors after running compileJava Task in gradle.

The gradle script throws number of compilation errors because some of the classes refers  java classes which resides in other modules. Now I'm writing script whose job is to move classes to modules which it is referring to.

So what i wanted to do is get compilation errors in script in TaskExecutionlistener which has afterExecute method. 
This afterexecute method provides state object which has failure but it doesnt give compilation errors.

How do I achieve this in gradle?

I have achieved this by writing compileJava output to log file and reading errors from log file but is there something which is better than my approach

Comment: I don't fully understand your question but before you start copying files from one module to another, first have a look at [multi-project builds](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html). Multi-project builds let you declare a dependency from one module to another.

Comment: @Benjamin Muschko Sorry, I didn't clear that out. I'm using this multimodule dependency but the module which I'm referring is common module which can be referred by other modules. But In common module there are some classes(which quite good number) are referring classes from other modules.  So i wanted to move these classes from common module to the ones where they can use these dependent classes.

Comment: OK, then I still don't understand the question. After fixing the class dependencies you should be good.

Comment: @Benjamin Muschko, I want to fix these programatically not manually. For that I need compilation errors in scripts. Right now i'm redirecting output to file and then reading this file in another script